# error - my categories are not shown - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I can't find the error, my categories are not shown according to their type, also does not throw laravel error..

blade.php

```php
@extends('store.template')

@section('content')

<!-- Page Content -->
<div style="margin-top: 70px;" class="container text-center">

<!-- Page Heading -->
<div  class="card bg-white ht-50 w-60">

  <h1 class="">{{$tipo->tipo}}</h1>
</div>


<div style="margin-top: 10px;" class="row">

    @foreach($categories as $category)
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 mb-4">

      <div class="card h-100">
        <a href="#">
          @if(!empty($category->image))
          <img class="card-img-top" src="{{url($category->image)}}" alt="">
          @else
            <img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt="">
          @endif
        </a>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title">
            <a href="{{ route('category-detail',['slug'=>$category->slug]) }}">{{$category->name}}</a>
          </h4>
          <p class="card-text">{{$category->descripcion}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach



</div>
<!-- /.row -->

</div>
<!-- /.container -->

@stop
```

controller:

```php
    public function categoryType($type)
    {

      $tipo = Tipo::where('tipo',$type)->first();
     //dd($tipo->categories);
      return view('store.categories-types')->with(['categories'=>$tipo->categories,'tipo'=>$tipo]);
    }
```

**in the table categories_type defined the categories**

[image]

**table categories:**

[image]

**error:**

[image]

Comment: does the `dd()` show your categories as expected?

Comment: dd() show =  Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#371 ▼
  #items: []
}

Comment: Could there be a typo, maybe? ... `{{$category->descripcion}}` => `{{$category->description}}`

Comment: fixed, but does not resolve the error :(

Comment: How many categories you have ? For debugging  you can use ```{{$categories->count()}}``` inside your blade file

Comment: $tipo = Tipo::where('tipo',$type)->first();  in this the column name is tipo or tip_id, As per the screenshot you have shared 'tipo_Id' is written, so shouldn't it be $tipo = Tipo::where('tipo_Id',$type)->first();

Comment: {{$categories->count()}} >  says i have 0

Comment: I missed uploading one more capture of the types table  https://i.imgur.com/SIicpBL.png

Comment: Please share your **$tipo relation model** where you have defined the `hasMany()` categories.